# Can't create SQL tables from Visual Studio 2017RC

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to work with a database at my university using the Visual Studio 2017 RC version. I haven't installed any SQL Server version on this (new) computer. I can connect to the database instance and see the default folders (Tables, Stored procedures, and so on), but when I click Add new table... I get the error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

Is this because I haven't installed SQL Server on my computer? As I recall it, I needed to do so with old versions of SQL Server, but I am not sure now. I think we use SQL Server 2014 at the university, at least we have the 2014 version of SSMS.

What would be the easiest way to fix this? I only need very basic functionality, such as add and fill tables and write stored procedures.

By the way, if I install a more recent version of SQL Server on my computer, will I be able to connect to the university's older version? (The reason why I ask is that this was not possible some years ago.)

Thanks!

Petter

Comment: you don't need local SQL Server if you're using remote SQL Server

Comment: Where SSMS is installed? On your computer?

Comment: "you don't need local SQL Server if you're using remote SQL Server"  Does this mean that I get this message becuase of a bug in 2017 RC? I think that would be very strange. As I said, I can connect fine and see the folders, I just can't create a table.

Comment: I'm not using SSMS at the moment. We have it at the university, but I thought of just using the Server Explorer pane in Visual Studio. I looked at the download, but it's huge (6GB). Even the Developer version seems big (2GB according to the install software.)

Comment: Hi ALex, yes I understand the difference, if you mean thet SQL Server is the actual server and that SSMS is just a nifty editor for it, at least that's how I use if.

Comment: maybe you don't have permissions to create tables?

Comment: just can install SSMS locally and connect to remote server, but actually you can do everything from VS. Check your permissions.

Comment: Hi again, I have now accessed an older instance of the database (which I used on another course). I can see the names of the tables and also the fields of the tables if I click the small arrow, but I can't show the data or add a new table, or even use Open table definition. Is this because I have no SQL Server version installed on my computer, or is it a bug in VS 2017 RC?

Comment: Thanks again. I do have persmisions for creating tables - I see the tables I have created before, I just haven't done so from this computer. Normally it's not a problem working with our databases remotely. Can it have to do with the fact that I am using Win10 (my old computer was Win7, but I can't try with it as it crashed).

Comment: which authentication you're using to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: Hi again, thanks for taking the time to try helping out. I am connecting uisng SQL Server login (as opposed to WIndows), if that is what you mean. Now I have also tried to connect to my db instance at my web host. It's the same thing there: I can see the table names and the stored procs, but I can't open anything - I just get the same error all the time.

Comment: if you use the same credentials, you should have the same permissions (if they aren't changed). Try to install SSMS and connect using it.

Comment: http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-management-studio-step-step-installation-guide/

Comment: Hi again, Final try I think - there must be a bug in the RC version. I have now tried an old WinForms project and connected from a clsDB class to my university's database. It works! SO it's just that the Server Explorer refuses to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me out, Alex. I will report this quite severe but to the VS team if I can. (Also thanks for the link to SSMS.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can be viewed in the comments. There appear to be a bug in Visual Studio 2017 RC that doesn't let the user see or edit tables etc in SQL Server.

(This question can be closed - hopefully it is of use to anyone having the same problem.)